# How to deserialize abstract object using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I need to deserialize abstract objects, but I always get an exception. I have 3 abstract classes in which I need to connect with each other.
I have a classes structure that looks like the following:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Child child = new Child(15, "child", "v1");
        final String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(child);

        final BaseClass baseClass = mapper.readValue(json, BaseClass.class);
        System.out.println(baseClass);
    }
}

@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        visible = true,
        property = "version"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = People.class, name = "v1"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Animal.class, name = "v2"),
})
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public abstract class BaseClass {
    public String version;

    public BaseClass(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}

@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        visible = true,
        property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog")
})
public abstract class Animal extends BaseClass {
    public String type;

    public Animal(String type, String version) {
        super(version);
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    public String name;

    @JsonCreator
    public Dog(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("type") String type, @JsonProperty("version") String version) {
        super(type, version);
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        visible = true,
        property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child.class, name = "child")
})
public abstract class People extends BaseClass {
    public String type;

    public People(String type, String version) {
        super(version);
        this.type = type;
    }
}

public class Child extends People {
    public int age;

    @JsonCreator
    public Child(@JsonProperty("id") int age, @JsonProperty("type") String type, @JsonProperty("version") String version) {
        super(type, version);
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

When I tried to run this code, I got the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.test.People` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (String)"{"type":"child","version":"v1","age":15}"; line: 1, column: 27]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1764)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1209)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:274)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:135)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:105)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:263)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:74)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4593)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3548)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3516)
    at com.test.Main.main(Main.java:30)
```

What I do wrong? 
 How can I fix this issue?